# Build target MyNotificationService: Framework not found

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods, ios-app-extension

I have a React Native app "MyApp" that has a "MyNotificationService" attached (i.e. `NotificationService.appex` embedded under the `Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content in Xcode` in target "MyApp").

Up until this point everything fine.

Now I want to add another pod to "MyApp" naming `pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'`, which does not have anything to do with `MyNotificationService`. I just want to install it, so I can access the `Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK` in "MyApp".

My Podfile looks like this

```
target 'MyApp' do
  
  use_unimodules!
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )

  # Additional Dependencies
  ...
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
 
  target 'MyNotificationService' do   
    use_native_modules!
    inherit! :complete
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'NO'
        # deletes each pods deployment target definition and instead uses the definition of the main project
        config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However, after I ran `pod install`, I tried to build the debug version of `MyApp` using XCode, but XCode complains:

```
Build Target MyNotificationService
Link MyNotificationService (arm64)

Directory not found for option '-F/Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-abcabcabcabcabc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/GoogleAppMeasurement'

Directory not found for option '-F/Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-abcabcabcabcabc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/GoogleMobileAds'

Directory not found for option '-F/Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-abcabcabcabcabc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/UserMessagingPlatform'
```

But MyNotificationService has nothing to do with these Frameworks `GoogleAppMeasurement`, `GoogleMobileAds` and `UserMessagingPlatform` - those belong to the `Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK` and only the main target `MyApp` should need them.

How can I tell `MyNotificationService` that it should not care about these frameworks?

Answer (score 0):

Did solve the problem with an abstract target, that has both "MyApp" and "MyNotificationService" as subtargets defined in it. The abstract target is not an actual Xcode target but rather a placeholder or a folder that defines the pods that both the "MyApp" and "MyNotificationService" should both have shared. To get "MyNotificationService" ignore everything related to the 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', the `pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'` is only defined in the subtarget "MyApp".

```
abstract_target 'Shared' do
  
  use_unimodules!
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )

  # Additional Dependencies
  ...

  target 'MyApp' do
    # no inherit statement means that target MyApp has all pods from the parent "Shared" accessible
    pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
  end

  target 'MyNotificationService' do 
      # no inherit statement means that target MyNotificationService has all pods from the parent "Shared" accessible
    use_native_modules!
  end
 
  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'NO'
        # deletes each pods deployment target definition and instead uses the definition of the main project
        config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
      end
    end
  end
end
```